# Revert all changes from Project in Visual Studio in a vs extenssion

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, vsix

I want to revert all changes from a project . I want to do it from code inside a visual extenssion I have on visual studio. How can I retrieve all files that are changed or added and revert or remove them?

Comment: Which VCS is this for? The answer is very different for different VCSs.

Comment: is for visual studio 2017 or 2019 . I have a  extension that changes some file and I want those changes to be reverted after the operations are finished. I want to add that functionality to the extension.

Comment: VCS == Version Control System. Git or TFVC? Or something else?

Comment: The Version Control System is Git .

Comment: Update the question to reflect this. (I mostly use git from the command line, but I know the git integration is changing in the updates to VS2019, so you might need to find multiple extension APIs and handle things dynamically.)